# Как заставить двигаться объект в javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
Как сделать так чтобы данный круг, с каждой итерацией цикла передвигался на 1 px ?
`let ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
let b = true;
while (b == true) {
    ball.style.left = ball.style.left + 1;
};
`
Вот так вот не работает.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас позиция круга инкрементируется бесконечно. Попробуйте применить setInterval

Comment: И что, что она бесконечно инкрементируется, суть в том что круг не передвигается вообще. Стоит на Ленин на пьедестале

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
let b = true;
ball.style.position = 'absolute';

while (b == true) {
  var left = ball.style.left;
  left = left.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  left = Number(left) + Number(1) + 'px'; // || '%'
  ball.style.left = left;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут несколько проблем:

1. В бесконечном цикле весь UI зависнет и не будет видно эффекта. Для начала можно воспользоваться `setInterval`. В дальнейшем перейти например на `requestAnimationFrame`
2. Изначально `ball.style.left` равен пустоте. Никакого значения нет. Пустая строка. Поэтому прибавление числа ничего не даст.
3. `ball.style.left` оперирует пикселями. Поэтому просто прибавление числа ничего не даст. Нужно ещё дописывать единицы измерения для перемещения, например пиксели

```js
let ball = document.querySelector(".ball");

setInterval(() => {
  ball.style.left = parseInt(ball.style.left || 0) + 1 + 'px';
}, 100);
```

```css
.ball {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: От души браточек

Comment: parseInt(ball.style.left || 0) зачем в данной функции оператор "или"?

Comment: @denikotin Изначально ball.style.left равен пустоте. Никакого значения нет. Пустая строка Поэтому прибавление числа ничего не даст. если этого значения нет, то по умолчанию оно будет 0

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое